# How to open two semantic-ui modals using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

I have an Angular Application. Created using SemanticUI (http://semantic-ui.com/). I use one modal to view some data and also there's a button in that modal to open another modal. When i open the second modal, it goes behind the first modal. I want to keep both modals. And I want to take the second modal to front. How can I do this ?

This is the code of first modal.

```
<div class="ui modal" id="viewMoreModal">
    <i class="close icon"></i>

    <div class="header">
        Episodes of {{series.description}}
    </div>
    <div class="content">

        <div class="ui grid">
            <div class="floated right pointing west">
                <button ng-click="openAddNewEpisodeModal()" class="ui purple button ">Add New Episode</button>
            </div>
            <div class="sixteen wide column">
                <table class="ui very compact celled table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Season</th>
                        <th>Episode</th>
                        <th>Alt. Episode Nr.</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Part</th>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                        <th>Release Date</th>
                        <th>Series</th>
                        <th>SubSeries</th>
                        <th>Tags</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="episode in episodes" onClick="HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');">
                        <td>{{episode.data.season}}</td>
                        <td>{{episode.data.episode}}</td>
                        <td>{{episode.data["episode-alt"]}}</td>
                        <td>{{episode.data.title}}</td>
                        <td>{{episode.data.part}}</td>
                        <td>{{episode.data.duration | secondsToDateTime | date:'HH:mm:ss' }}</td>
                        <td>{{episode.data.date}}</td>
                        <td>{{episode.data.series}}</td>
                        <td>{{episode.data.subseries}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a ng-repeat="sub_tag in episode.data.tags" class="ui mini orange tag label"><span>{{sub_tag}}</span></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="floated right pointing west">
                <button ng-click="openAddNewEpisodeModal()" class="ui purple button ">Add New Episode</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my second modal. This opens when user click on the "Add New Episode" button in first modal.

```
<div class="ui united modal" id="addNewEpisodeModal">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Add New Episode
    </div>
    <div class="content">



    </div>
</div>
```

Please tell me how to fix this issue.
This is how I open those models.

```
$scope.openAddNewEpisodeModal = function () {
    $('#addNewEpisodeModal').modal('show');
};
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying the second modal's z-index?